# Validate if all NSLocalizedString are in their proper Localized.string?

Tags: xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have an app available in 3 languages.

Is there a way to be sure all NSLocalizedString are in their proper Localized.string?

In other word, how did you manage\be sure all string are in all Localised.string. (for project with dozen of language, can be a risk to forget one)

Thanks!